# URI Scheme, launch program in its directory

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, uri

I have registered URI scheme for my app. When I open it with "Run.." or in browser, it runs in hosted directory. For ex. Ive opened url in webpage, program's working dir is in browser.

What I want?
I want to run program test.exe located at

> C:\data\test.exe

and to use dir.

> C:\data

so it could use other data in relative path.
so test.exe would access file .\file.txt without using absolute path

Hope I wrote it understandable, sorry for bad English.

Comment: Just change the working directory to the application in your application.

Comment: I dont know how. Ok I have defined exactly this http://prntscr.com/1xx5yd and lhmp key looks like this http://prntscr.com/1xx664